# CodeIgniter: Is it safe to delete index.html from all folders?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter. I notice that all CodeIgniter folders (cache, config, controllers, core, errors, etc...) contains an index.html file that basically says "Directory access is forbidden". Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think it is possible to get to any of these folders from the web based on CodeIgniter's default configuration.

What is the purpose of these index.html files? Can I just delete them, or do I leave them alone?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The purpose of them is to prevent the contents of the directory from displaying if directory listing is enabled on your server.  Apache servers by default have directory listing enabled.

There are several instances where given the right circumstances you might be able to attempt to browse to a folder directly.  These would mainly be caused by a server which is not configured properly, or an exploit.  Therefore it is really best if you just leave the index.html files alone (they aren't hurting anything, and they don't take up that much space).

I'd even go as far as to suggest that you too add an index.html file to any and all folders which you create.

Answer (score 4):

They are there for fail-safes, ie. if for some reason the directory structure would get to be publicly browsable.

I can't see any reason to remove them.

Answer (score 4):

If your codeigniter installation (system and app folders) is outside of your public server directory, then they're not going to help with anything since they could never be served. In that case, it doesn't matter whether they exist or not, since you could never get to their directories anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I say remove them for two reasons:

1) If Apache is configured to allow directory browsing, then it doesn't matter what your index.html says. So claiming that "Directory access if forbidden" when it's really not, amounts to security through obscurity, which is an undesirable security strategy.

2) I disagree with the idea that "if it's not hurting anything, just leave it alone". I've spent many an hour trying to figure out the purpose of a particular piece of code, only later to find out that it wasn't doing anything at all. Remove unused code. The inheritors of your projects will curse you less.

Comment: Actually, I just found a use for them. They act as placeholders for otherwise empty directories, and many directories in a fresh CI install are empty be default.

And if you're using GIT like I am, then placeholder files are handy to maintain directory structure. I just removed a bunch of the index.html files from my repo, and lost a bunch of needed directories. Git reset hard time :-)

Comment: This should be correct answer ... and behaviour of GIT to not commit empty dir, It has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

They are for your security, if someone tries to access your folder on the server by your domain URL (*if your server is configured in a wrong way*), it will prevent you from loading those files by triggering that HTML file

It would be safe for you to keep the file indeed.