# CodeIgniter how do I make 403 forbidden page display the same default one

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

[image: Default inside CI]
Notice that inside every folder in CI have an html page called 'index.html' which contain

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and thus if you open the folder using the url it will produce the access forbidden page as shown in my image above. However when I copy pasted the index.html into another new folder that is created by me, it showed the page below image. I want it to show the page exactly as the one created by codeigniter, which file do I need to configure to make the page show the forbidden page like that ?

[image: Created my own]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter: Is it safe to delete index.html from all folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373601/codeigniter-is-it-safe-to-delete-index-html-from-all-folders)

Comment: @CPHPython Hi, I think my question is totally different from the link that you gave. I am asking how to make the page to be displayed as how the default one displayed by CI while the link you gave is wanting to delete the index.html altogether.

Comment: The answers provided in that question explain that the error you are seeing is a self-protection mechanism of CodeIgniter that prevents users online to access directories listings (which is considered unsafe). The `.htaccess` files allow users to be redirected to the pages you want the them to see, perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510478/codeigniter-error-403) may help you understand better why and what you should place on them. If you believe the problem you raised is solved and may not help other people you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, should have copied the .htaccess file too.